# Should I use an interface or an abstract hierarchy to update a view?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, interface, abstract-class

I have an `updateGUI` method that can receive two different objects, either `object1` or `object2` that can be used to update two different views `view1` or `view2`.

`view1` and `view2` are sub-classed from the abstract class `ViewSuper`, and a factory class creates the appropriate view. Each `view` has it's own implementation of the methods `initialize` and `update`.

```
public void updateGUI(Object object){

    GUIFactory viewFactory = new GUIFactory(object);
    ViewSuper view = viewFactory.getView();
    view.initialize();
    view.update();
}
```

Now my question is, should I make `initialize` and `update` two abstract methods in the `ViewSuper` class OR create a seperate `interface` with these methods and make `ViewSuper` implement this interface?

I'm confused because both the methods seem to be specific to a view hierarchy but at the same time it defines general functionality which is what interfaces (as per my understanding) is used for.

If the answer is to go with abstract methods, please provide an example where I could use the above functionality as an interface.

Comment: How does `GUIFactory` handle a plain `Object`? Passing `Object`s is a code smell.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, Abstract class and interface serve the same purpose.

Case 1: Any common method among view

View1 and View2 have `update` and `initialize` but `delete` has the common functionality. In this case, we need a common method where it is implemented -> Abstract class -- and can be used in both views.

Case 2: No common functionality.

If there isn't any common functionality among views (Which is not in your case, as there is an abstract class defined). Then go with only interface.

General:

Use combination of interface and abstract class.

**Interface:**

```
public interface IView {

    void initialize();
    void update();
    void delete();
}
```

**Abstract class**

```
public abstract class AbstractView implements IView{

    abstract void initialize();
    abstract void update();

    void delete() {
        // do delete operation
    }
}
```

**View class**

```
public class View1 extends AbstractView implements IView{
}

public class View2 extends AbstractView implements IView{
}
```